# why is the rotate function not working no matter what i do?

Tags: html, css

When I try to use the `transform: rotate(xDeg);` (in my case `transform: rotate(90deg)`) it just doesn't rotate no matter what tutorial I follow or what I do.

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

.rotate {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 200px;
}

.rotate:hover {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="rotate"></div>
```

Comment: Rotates fine for me. Then again, rotating a square 90 degrees would be imperceptible. Adding a transition might make it more obvious

Comment: Or rotating it 45 degrees.

Comment: Rotating a square by 90 degrees is just going to show the square again, it is rotating, you just can't see it. Add some border radius to some corners or something.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should add `transition` otherwise you will not see the difference

```css
body{
  background-color:black;
}

.rotate {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background-color:red;
  margin:200px;
  transition: transform .5s ease-in-out;
}

.rotate:hover {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="e.css">
<div class="rotate"></div>
</html>
```

Comment: i am not sure exactly.... its quite strange, anyway i forgot to say this: thx for your support

Comment: Probably because the comments already resolved the answer and since they are logged before your answer. Kind of unfair since the time it takes to post a complete answer is more than it is to post a comment.

Answer (score 3):

When you try to use the `transform: rotate(90Deg)` it rotates but due to square you will not see the rotation because it rotates in a fraction of seconds but when you apply transition on rotating you can see it clearly.

Now, if you look at the `rectangle` you can understand clearly what I'm talking about.

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  background-color: black;
}

.rotate {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 20px;
}

.rotate:hover {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.rac {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 50px 20px;
}

.rac:hover {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="rotate"></div>
<div class="rac"></div>
```